# Creating a log for WCF operations / getting app directory

Tags: wcf, logging, io

I want my WCF service to log errors / operations, etc.

I have a very simple logging class but finding the directory to create / write to is returning a null reference exception:

```
    public static string Path()
    {
        return Path.GetDirectoryName
            (Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
    }
```

This works in say a console app but not WCF, perhaps there is a different convention?

Or alternatively are there any simple libraries for logging in WCF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF has built-in message logging, following links should help you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx

http://geekswithblogs.net/mnf/archive/2008/10/03/use-wcf-message-logging.aspx

http://mkdot.net/blogs/dejan/archive/2008/10/23/wcf-tracing-and-message-logging.aspx

Comment: Thanks, do you happen to know of the top of your head if this will only log operations in .svc components? I have many plain .cs classes that my .svc components (or possible aspx pages as well) reference, will this be able to log errors that happen inside these classes?

Comment: It logs at the svc boundry so you'll see any exceptions that bubble up. In debug you might want to specify includeExceptionDetailInFaults set to true in service behaviours. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649234.aspx